# Can not make HTTP get call to web API from noddemcu lua v3

Tags: nodemcu

Dears, i've tried below code to connect to iis hosted API in my machine but always failed

if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { return; }

Serial.print("connecting to "); Serial.println("http://192.168.1.106:8080/SendCommands");

// Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections WiFiClient client; const int httpPort = 8080; if (!client.connect("http://192.168.1.106:8080SendCommands/", httpPort)) { Serial.println("connection failed");

}

I've tried many ways but same issue
tried to use esphttpclient from below url
https://github.com/Caerbannog/esphttpclient
as it has async calls to not affect performance
but always get below error from arduino IDE
ambiguating new declaration of 'size_t ets_strlen(const char*)'

I do not know what is actually the problem